# Tor exited during startup. 6.0.7

Tags: configuration, startup

I am trying to start Tor Browser 6.0.7 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1.
Upon attempting to launch I get the following message:

﻿﻿﻿"Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start."

I have looked in the Tor package contents and the Application Support folder and have been unable to locate a torrc file at all. Nor is there TorBrowser-data folders that I have been following other Questions to try to locate. I have also attempted to create this folder with the torrc.sample file with no avail. It seems there are solutions to this with older versions of Tor / mac OS, but in this particular configuration those solutions don't work.

Please Help! There must be others experiencing this?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. I get this message when I launch TorBrowser with version 6 and 7. Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start.